# Was Naruto's design inspired by Goku's?

Tags: naruto, dragon-ball

[image]

[image]

Comparing Naruto and Goku, we can see that Naruto has the same hair and eye color as Goku from his Super Saiyan form and also, their jumpsuit color schemes are similar.

Comment: @LoganM Hey say something man!!

Comment: I'm not sure what you want me to say. All I did was remove [tag:identification-request], which doesn't apply to this question because the question isn't asking to identify any particular work.

Comment: Well, blue and orange are [complementary colors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complementary_colors) so you'll often see them paired together. If Naruto were a clone of Goku, he would first need to grow some muscles, and then get rid of the whiskers on his face.

Comment: Seeing the answer given, I think if you would change the negative tone from your question to something more positive like  "Was Naruto based on Goku" or "Was Naruto's design influenced by Goku's" or what not, I think it would improve the question a lot and get you more upvotes instead.

Comment: To be honest, I'm not even sure why you are getting so many downvotes, without even a single comment explaining why.

Comment: @PeterRaeves Agreed. I think only the title is misleading. I'm sure it wasn't actually what he was trying ask.

Comment: i did not downvote this question, but i'm really tempted to. Its a reflexive action because of the absurdity of the question. Its like asking if thor is zeus' clone because they both use thunder and are white

Comment: I only see the hair as being the same color, Goku's eyes as Super Saiyen are [Teal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teal) (like other [Super](http://vignette2.wikia.nocookie.net/dragonball/images/a/a0/RB2_OVA_new_animation_1.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20100811125445) [Saiyens](http://vignette4.wikia.nocookie.net/dragonball/images/1/17/GokuAndGohanHTCnv.png/revision/latest?cb=20110806183243)) while Naruto's are clearly [blue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blue)

Answer (score 11):

To put it precisely, **no**. As [@Gao](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/22181/is-naruto-a-clone-of-goku#comment31529_22181) mentions in his comment, the difference in appearance between the two is obvious enough, keeping their clothing similarity aside. Moreover, Naruto and Goku exist in different series universes and hence they're not *clones* of each other.

However, the similarity between the characters are astonishingly similar.

This is because Masashi Kishimoto, the creator of the *Naruto* series, was deeply inspired by Akira Toriyama's (creator of *Dragon Ball* series) works. Kishimoto often describes how Toriyama's works influenced him and encouraged his own works.

> **Q: When was the first time that you thought of becoming a mangaka, and why?**
>
> Masashi Kishimoto: At some point between second and fourth grade I got into Akira Toriyama Sensei’s Dr. Slump anime and Dragon Ball manga. I loved his characters. I was especially attached to Dr. Slump’s Arale and Dragon Ball’s Goku. Also, his art really appealed to me. There was something about his cartoony drawing style that felt right, more so than realistic drawings. I thought to myself, I want to become like Toriyama Sensei.
>
> <sub>[INTERVIEW: Masashi Kishimoto - Feb 13, 2012](https://shonenjump.viz.com/blog/posts/interview-masashi-kishimoto-59)</sub>

Masashi Kishimoto openly admits that the character Naruto is inspired by the hero of Dragon Ball, Goku.

> Kishimoto cites Akira Toriyama's Dragon Ball series as one of his influences, noting that Goku, the protagonist, was a key factor when creating Naruto Uzumaki due to his energetic and mischievous personality.
>
> <sub>Art Collection: Uzumaki, page 139</sub>

As for the clothing, both the characters are often portrayed in orange-blue color schemes (although it changes series wise). The reason for this uncommon combination is, to make the character appear more active and pop out to the viewers.

From [TVTropes](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/OrangeBlueContrast):

> Basic complementary color theory states that when two contrasting colors are put together, they "pop," so the natural technique is to color films to have a strong, contrasting palette.

Bright color schemes are used so that the character would certainly catch people's attention.

> The orange in his costume makes Naruto "pop" and the blue parts are often used as [complements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complementary_colors).
>
> <sub>source: [Naruto Uzumaki (Wikipedia)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naruto_Uzumaki)</sub>

Also, as I have mentioned above, Naruto was deeply influenced by Goku. Therefore their are very similar (that includes the color schemes too).

For more details regarding the creation and concept of the two characters, check out their Wikia articles:

- [**Goku**](http://dragonball.wikia.com/wiki/Goku#Concept_and_creation)
- [**Naruto Uzumaki**](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Naruto#Creation_and_Conception)

Comment: At lease compare the color schemes their similar

Comment: @Daniel I've added a few points regarding the color schemes. And for the sake of it, they are *not* clones of each other. I've mentioned several times in my answer that Naruto was inspired by Goku. Kishimoto designed Naruto after Toriyama's Goku. So yes, there are similarites between the two. But that doesn't make them *clones* of each other. It's common for a mangaka's work to be influenced after someone else's.